# How to sum two Dataframes and remove the old values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-3.7

I have two dataframes that I need to join on one key and sum the values of another while removing the original values (or probably creating a new df).

First dataframe with a few elements look like

```
product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 6                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-6                                                       
barcode                   121212221   
inventory_item_id       256256256        

product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 2                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-2                                                       
barcode                   121212222   
inventory_item_id       256256257        

product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 8                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-8                                                       
barcode                   121212223   
inventory_item_id         256256258
```

Second looks like

```
inventory_item_id       256256256                                                        
location_id             2626262626                                                           
available               3                                                                  

inventory_item_id       256256257                                                        
location_id             2626262626                                                           
available               2                                                                  

inventory_item_id       256256258                                                        
location_id             2626262626                                                           
available               7                                                                  

inventory_item_id       256256258                                                        
location_id             2626262623                                                           
available               2  

inventory_item_id       256256257                                                        
location_id             2626262623                                                           
available               2  

inventory_item_id       256256258                                                        
location_id             2626262629                                                           
available               2
```

Both DF's have other columns that I didn't include here but will want in the final output. So I want a final output with the available values summed up IE

```
product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 6                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-6                                                       
barcode                   121212221   
inventory_item_id         256256256
available                 3 

product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 2                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-2                                                       
barcode                   121212222   
inventory_item_id         256256257
available                 4        

product_id                123123123123                             
title                     Maroon/Pink / 8                          
price                     26.00                                    
sku                       111111/PINK-8                                                       
barcode                   121212223   
inventory_item_id         256256258
available                 11
```

And not immediately, necessary but eventually would like to be able to filter these by location_id.

Thanks so much!

Comment: elcapitan, can you give us a dict of these, like the output from  print(df[0:3].to_dict()) so we can easily create the dataframe? thx!

Comment: Yup one second! Just cleaning the data a little bit so you can work with it. There are thousands of entries so i want to make sure I get some with consistent id's

Comment: Hopefully this is enoguh data

https://gist.github.com/CaptainJeff/8f35234bbec147176fe07427522408f5

Comment: Can you share the data in a more clear and easy to use format? CSV is good, so is the output of `.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to SQL's inner joins, I took a look at [this page](https://datacarpentry.org/python-ecology-lesson/05-merging-data/) to come up with my answer.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, 
                     left_on='inventory_item_id', 
                     right_on='inventory_item_id')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. It just merges the two dataframes but doesn't sum the available values or remove the old values. So there are tons of records with the same `inventory_item_id` instead of just a single inventory_item_id row per id

Answer (score 0):

Quite long, hopefully somebody comes along with a shorter and more succint version.
I copied your text and created two text files, one for each of your dataframes.

```
#inventory.txt
         0
0   product_id 123123123123 ...
1   title Maroon/Pink / 6 ...
2   price 26.00 ...
3   sku 111111/PINK-6 ...
4   barcode 121212221
5   inventory_item_id 256256256
6   product_id 123123123123 ...
7   title Maroon/Pink / 2 ...
8   price 26.00 ...
9   sku 111111/PINK-2 ...
10  barcode 121212222
11  inventory_item_id 256256257
12  product_id 123123123123 ...
13  title Maroon/Pink / 8 ...
14  price 26.00 ...
15  sku 111111/PINK-8 ...
16  barcode 121212223
17  inventory_item_id 256256258


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#first dataframe and some  cleanup
m = (pd.read_csv('inventory.txt', header=None)
     [0]
     .str.strip()
     .str.split(n=1,expand=True)
     .pivot(columns=0,values=1)
     .fillna(method='ffill')
     .dropna()
     .drop_duplicates('inventory_item_id')
     .set_index('inventory_item_id')
    )

m

inventory_item_id    product_id       title         price      sku          barcode                     
256256256           123123123123    Maroon/Pink / 6     26.00   111111/PINK-6   121212221
256256257           123123123123    Maroon/Pink / 2     26.00   111111/PINK-2   121212222
256256258           123123123123    Maroon/Pink / 8     26.00   111111/PINK-8   121212223
```

second dataframe

```
#inventory1.txt
       0
0   inventory_item_id 256256256 ...
1   location_id 2626262626 ...
2   available 3 ...
3   inventory_item_id 256256257 ...
4   location_id 2626262626 ...
5   available 2 ...
6   inventory_item_id 256256258 ...
7   location_id 2626262626 ...
8   available 7 ...
9   inventory_item_id 256256258 ...
10  location_id 2626262623 ...
11  available 2
12  inventory_item_id 256256257 ...
13  location_id 2626262623 ...
14  available 2
15  inventory_item_id 256256258 ...
16  location_id 2626262629 ...
17  available 2
```

clean up second dataframe

```
n = (pd.read_csv('inventory1.txt',header=None)
     [0]
     .str.strip()
     .str.split(n=1,expand=True)
     .pivot(columns=0,values=1)
     .fillna(method='ffill')
     .dropna()
     .drop_duplicates('available')
     .set_index('inventory_item_id')
     .assign(available = lambda x: x.available.astype('int64'))
    )

n


inventory_item_id   location_id     available   
  256256256           2626262626        3
  256256257           2626262626        2
  256256258           2626262626        7
```

Next step is to join the two dataframes,
create a new column that cumulatively sums the available column values
and finally flip (transpose) the headers to rows

```
p = (m.join(n,how='left')
     .assign(available = lambda x : x.available.cumsum())
     .reset_index()
     .transpose())

p

                        0                 1                   2
inventory_item_id   256256256           256256257           256256258
product_id          123123123123        123123123123        123123123123
title               Maroon/Pink / 6     Maroon/Pink / 2     Maroon/Pink / 8
price               26.00               26.00               26.00
sku                 111111/PINK-6       111111/PINK-2       111111/PINK-8
barcode             121212221           121212222           121212223
location_id         2626262626          2626262626          2626262626
available           3                   5                   12
```

Last step to make it look like what you have in your question:

```
    (pd.concat([p[0],p[1],p[2]],
                axis=0))

inventory_item_id          256256256
product_id                 123123123123
title                      Maroon/Pink / 6
price                      26.00
sku                        111111/PINK-6
barcode                    121212221
location_id                2626262626
available                  3
inventory_item_id          256256257
product_id                 123123123123
title                      Maroon/Pink / 2
price                      26.00
sku                        111111/PINK-2
barcode                    121212222
location_id                2626262626
available                  5
inventory_item_id          256256258
product_id                 123123123123
title                      Maroon/Pink / 8
price                      26.00
sku                        111111/PINK-8
barcode                    121212223
location_id                2626262626
available                  12
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is getting closer but there are multiple references to some values IE there are three available columns one has 3, 5, and 12. I'm not sure which one is accurate

Comment: @elcapitan, in your question, u stated that u wanted the available summed up, and showed an example DataFrame with a cumulative sum on each inventory item is for the same product id.  My answer reflects that, with the final DataFrame that is concatenated . If that is not what u want, then kindly explain with an example